# OpenCV3 contrib を Mac にインストール

Tags: macos, opencv

OpenCV contrib を homebrew でインストールしました．

`brew install opencv3 --with-contrib`

pgk_comfig_path は以下のように設定しました．

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

上記のDirectoryにopencv.pcがあることは確認済です．
この状態でc++のコードをコンパイルしようとしたところ以下のようなエラーが

> Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>   Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'opencv' found

mac os Sierraを使用しています．
どなたか解決策を教えていただけないでしょうか．．．．

Comment: `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$usr/...` の`$`は誤記でしょうか？該当記述を`/usr/...`とすると結果が変わりますか？

Comment: そこを間違えていたようで，コンパイルできました．ありがとうございます！